# Cassandra Primary Key with no Clustering Key

Tags: cassandra

I have a table that contains words with their frequencies in Cassandra table(word, frequenc0y, frequency1).
Can I make the primary key consisting of only word as Partition key? if not, can I use word also as Clustering key?

Comment: What queries do you want to perform? You can make word as single key, and then you'll be able to retrieve the frequency for the given word.

Answer (score 2):

You have no constraints, except that you cannot reuse your columns, so you can put only a single column in your *PRIMARY KEY* definition, that will specifically be your *PARTITION KEY*.

BTW, if that's all you need, and depending on your *UPDATE* capabilities on the `frequency0` and `frequency1` columns, that could be a job for *counter* columns. Have a look at the official documentation about counters:

- [Creating a counter table](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html)
- [Using a counter](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCounters.html)

HTH.